# Three simultaneous SQL queries in one table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have the following table structure:

```
                 ----------------------------------
                 ID | Acces | Group | User | Gate |
                 ----------------------------------
                 1  |   1   |  TR   | tsv  | TL-23|
                 ----------------------------------
```

And I have a page with 3 functions:

- Select group to see all gates where selected group has access.
- Select gate to see all groups which have access to selected gate.
- Select group to see all users that belong to selected group.

So basically:

```
  SELECT Gate WHERE Group = TR 
  SELECT Group WHERE Gate = TL-23
  SELECT User WHERE Group = TR
```

What I am trying to achieve is: The user should be able to run the all three queries in any order without the results of the former queries dissappearing.

Now, I know multi-threading is no longer possible in PHP, but  there must be a way to temporarily save the results of a specific query until the same query is made again.

Any help and suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give at least some more rows of your table with different gates, groups and users? Maybe providing a sqlfiddle.com with some data? I would like to do a matrix with this data. It will be fun :)

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a mySQL question or a SQL question.  It It appears you want to retain the data from each request and then re-render it prior to the additional data achieved on each query.  If you constantly append to an object that will persist though the new inquiries (lots of ways to do this) and append the new data to the array, and render the array each time... then you likely achieve the desired result.  I don't think this is a mySQL problem as much as it is a PHP and retention of data across requests. (variables as @lascort eloquently put)

Comment: @xQbert It can be an SQL question if someone offers an SQL-related solution. As far as I know, there may have been some clause that allows multi-threaded querying.

Comment: Here you go @JorgeCampos : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40c62/2

Comment: This is possibly an example of an [x/y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). `The user should be able to run the all three queries in any order without the results of the former queries disappearing` - this sounds very much like you're reusing variables or some other such code error which has very little to do with the question as asked (which is "confused"). As there's no code in the question it's not really possible to say what the problem is/was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, PHP has never done MT out of the box, but can (still) with the use of pcntl extensions.

That said, that isn't the sauce you seek.

If you simply want the user on the front-end to interact 3 separate times, without having to hit the DB once the first time, twice the second (to redo both the first and the new query) you may benifit from caching the results of each call in the user's session.

If you actually want to make the 3 queries in a relational way at one exact time, try `JOIN`s.

If you simply want to make all 3 separate queries at (what is essentially) the same time, look into `TRANSACTION`s.

Hope that helps.

Comment: With modern browsers, storing data in the user's session is risky because it is susceptible to unexpected changes.

Comment: How so?  The Session is saved to the server, the only thing in the browser is the Cookie that references the Session ID.  Please elaborate.